# How to control TablePagination from material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When page loaded initially, the page rows should start from 1.
but It starts from 25 like below.
[image]

the data 1-25 and 26-50 are same. so when I clicked `<` button, data doesn't changed.
but when I click `>`, it works just fine.

 only problem is setting initial number of rows.

this is my code.

```js
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(25);

          <TablePagination
            component="div"
            count={adminInfo && adminInfo.total}
            page={page}
            onChangePage={handleChangePage}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
            onChange={moveToNextPage}
           />
```

Thanks for reading

- Edited
  The reason why I didn't set `page` value to 0 was
  If I send 0 to server, server takes 0 and 1 as same values.
  So when I clicked `>` button, 0 to 1 showed same data.
  But I've solved this problem in api query like below.

```js
//before solving
await axios.get(`${BASEURL}`+(page ? `page=${page}` : 'page=1')

//after solving
await axios.get(`${BASEURL}`+(page ? `page=${page+1}` : 'page=1')
```

simply added `+1` to `page` value.

Comment: Maybe start at page 0? `const [page, setPage] = useState(0);`. If this isn't the issue then can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that accurately reproduces the issue you are seeing? Though I guess it doesn't matter if the first 2 pages of results are identical. Not really sure what your issue is then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the first value for `page` is 0